# jquery datepicker reopening in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

'm seeing an anoying behavior of datepicker in IE9.  The datepicer does work, but keeps poping up again after the selected date is clicked on the popup calendar.  The user has to click away from the popup calendar to close it.  Here are the sequence of events:

1) User clickes on datepicker text box

2) Calendar pops up

3) User clicks on desired date

4) Date is inserted in text box AND calendar pop up immediatly opens again.

5) User has to click away from calendar popup

6) Calendar popup closes

This doesn't happen in Chrome or FF.  There, once the selected date is clicked the calendar popup closes and stays closed unless the user clickes the calendar text box again.

Does it sound like I've set up the datepicker wrong or is this a bug?

Datepicker Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:submit, button").button();
    $("#VNH").css("color", "#006600");
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $("#tools_dialog").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

And for after ajax:

```
$("#SNH").live('click', function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "news.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(html){
            $("#topcontainer").html(html);
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

Using jquery-1.6.2.min.js and  jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js

Thanks for any help.

Best Regards,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the date picker twice (once the DOM has loaded and after your AJAX call). Try removing the .datepicker property from within the AJAX call.

This line: 
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'             });

Comment: Without the ajax callback the datepicker doesn't work at all.  It has to be rebound after ajax.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: If I remove the .datepicker property from the AJAX call I still get the repeating pop-up behavior and the datepicker no longer works after the AJAX call (nothing happens when the text box is clicked).